# How to force logout a (non-present) user from CAS server

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

Is there a way to revoke/invalidate a user's CAS session from a client application without the user visiting the CAS server's logout page?

The situation is that a user could be accessing 1-n services that all authenticate off the CAS server. One of those client services is in charge of user accounts, and sometimes needs to terminate an account. If that user is logged in to 1-n other services, those sessions need to be immediately destroyed. Normally this is accomplished by the user clicking "logout", but if the user isn't present, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check regularly if the ticket has expired or not.
Check this subject 
[CAS and Spring-Security: regularly check if a ticket has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856972/cas-and-spring-security-regularly-check-if-a-ticket-has-expired)

Comment: But the CAS ticket won't have expired, since the logout will only have happened in the client application.